# ¿Porque no puedo acceder a la clase R desde este metodo?

Tags: java, android

Estoy empezando en Android y me he encontrado con que desde el siguiente metodo que os voy a mostrar no me lee un string que tengo puesto en la clase R, es decir en el archivo "strings.xml" los cuales son:

```
<string name="registrarse">Registrarse</string>
<string name="iniciar">Iniciar Sesion</string>
```

El metodo esta en el MainActivity y es el siguiente:

```
public void RegistroInicio (View view){

    String InfoBtn = btInicio.getText().toString();

    if(InfoBtn.equals(R.string.iniciar)){
                IniciarSesion(view);
    }else if(InfoBtn.equals(R.string.registrarse)){
            Registrarse(view);
        }
}
```

La cosa es que si lo sustituyo por texto entre comillas, "Iniciar Sesion" si que me funciona. ¿Que podría estar fallando?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy buenas Enzo,
Lo que se encuentra en la clase R es una referencia y por tanto para poder acceder a los string definidos deberías hacer:

```
context.getString(R.string.iniciar)
```

Espero que te pueda ayudar. Un saludo

Comment: Si muchas gracias! me ha funcionado así:

        if(InfoBtn.equals(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.iniciar))){
                    IniciarSesion(view);
        }else if(InfoBtn.equals(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.registrarse))){
                Registrarse(view);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la documentación :
[Recursos de Strings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource?hl=es-419)

Para acceder a los recursos no es suficiente usar el id (`R.string.registrarse`), debes usar el método [getString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context?hl=es-419#getString(int)), ejemplo:

Declaración:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
</resources>
```

Obtención del valor de `hello` :

```
String valorHello = getString(R.string.hello);
```

Es importante comentar que necesitas el Contexto para usar [getString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context?hl=es-419#getString(int)), en tu caso tu método se encuentra en una Activity por lo tanto puedes usar [getApplicationContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context?hl=es-419#getApplicationContext()) para obtener el contexto:

```
public void RegistroInicio (View view){

    String InfoBtn = btInicio.getText().toString();

    if(InfoBtn.equals(getApplicacionContext().getText(R.string.iniciar))){
                IniciarSesion(view);
    }else if(InfoBtn.equals(getApplicacionContext().getText(R.string.registrarse))){
            Registrarse(view);
    }
}
```